# Word that can both mean "selection" and "adjustment"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a kind of similarity between "selection" and "adjustment":
When we have 5 options, and we "**select**" one option, we are "**narrowing** down out of 5 options, **which one we will get in the end**"

But when we have an existing object, say a house, and we "**adjust**" the house to be different, we are also "**narrowing down** out of all possible houses that could result from all possible adjustments, **which one we will get in the end**"

**Is there a word that captures both of these connotations?**

Sample sentence:

- I have ___en the final version of the design. I first chose one out of the 5 basic designs, and then adjusted it according to our needs". Another: "I have ____en a design, but I'm not sure yet whether its the right one. I chose one out of the 5 basic designs, and adjusted it somewhat, but not sure if it should be adjusted more.

**Edit**: people still seem confused as to what exactly adjustment and selection have to do with each other: they are both ways of narrowing down to get to one out of a larger set of possibillities. With selection you choose one out of "pre-existing" set of possibillities, but with adjustment you narrow it down to one out of a set of possibilities (namely all possible outcomes that result from some kind of adjustment to a pre-existing object).

So the common characteristic is "narrowing down to one out of a set of possibillities"

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence that would use it?

Comment: What do you need this for, your program?

Comment: The second case actually consists of selecting (making up one's mind about what or how) and then adjusting (making the changes accordingly.) They are distinct.

Comment: Also, *change* and any of its synonyms could have an object.

Comment: @Kris, I would not call making up ones mind "selecting" until you've taken the action that causes it to be "selected" (i.e. telling someone "I select this one", or pressing some button that causes one option to be selected)

Comment: @JasonBassford, ok : "I have ___en the final version of the design. I first chose one out of the 5 basic designs, and then adjusted it according to our needs". Another: "I have ____en a design, but I'm not sure yet whether its the right one. I chose one out of the 5 basic designs, and adjusted it somewhat, but not sure if it should be adjusted more"

Comment: I suppose you ought to think out of *that* box to see the point in the right perspective.

Comment: @kris, im not sure what u mean. Do u have something specific in mind?

Comment: Further, doesn't adjusting something *automatically* imply first selecting it? How can you adjust something *without* having selected it first?

Comment: I selected two shirts but bought only one.

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust"? Do you mean you change your selection (e.g. blue shirt to green shirt), or do you mean you do something with it (e.g. buy the blue shirt, then add a company logo later)? Your first example suggests the former, but I'm not quite sure what to make of 'adjusting' a house in your second example.

Comment: @lawrence, adjusting a house could be e.g. rebuilding the kitchen or painting the walls

Comment: So yes by adjust i mean to change/alter a preexisting object.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Although you can consider the *final* product to be 'one out of many possibilities', the *adjustment* itself isn't a 'selection' process - it is a 'change' process. If you are really talking about the *final* product and not the change process, you're back to 'selection' with no sense of 'adjustment' (i.e. the change process is out of scope of the 'selection'). So are you looking for a term that encompasses both *choice* and *change*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our Help Center specifically rules picking names for programming purposes is out of scope for our site.

Comment: You seem to be asking us to help you name your programming stuff. We don’t do that here.

Answer (score 2):

It feels a bit tenuous as "selection" and "adjustment" are distinct processes for your use as far as I can tell, but **refinement** might suit.

e.g.:

> We **refined** our choice of house.
>
> The **refinement** process involved evaluation of all options as well as consideration of possible adjsutments.

Comment: They are indeed distinct processes, that's why I'm trying to find a word that captures both of them... but yes, refinement is in the right direction, thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

How about [customise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/customize):

> to build, fit, or alter according to individual specifications